# Visual studio datetime format in debugger

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

It looks like the debugger in vs 2023 is using Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture to display the DateTime
[image]

That result is in therefore formatted as the US format

[image]

Is it possible to change the behavior and having vs use the local setting format instead(dd-MM-yyyy)?

This is driving me crazy and make my life way harder when debugging a date algorithm

Comment: Override the format with `DebuggerDisplay` line in `autoexp.cs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK thanks to Paweł Łukasik I found the answer. It seems convoluted but it's working.

1. Locate the file autoexp.cs ( under here for me `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\Original`)
2. Update the file as needed, I added that `[assembly: DebuggerDisplay("{Day}/{Month}/{Year} {Hour}:{Minute}:{Second}", Target = typeof(DateTime))] [assembly: DebuggerDisplay("{Day}/{Month}/{Year} {Hour}:{Minute}:{Second} TZ:{Offset.Hours}:{Offset.Minutes}", Target = typeof(DateTimeOffset))]`.
3. Find the csc.exe it was here for me `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn`
4. backup th`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\Original\autoexp.dll`
5. Compile the cs file using the following command line `csc /t:library "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\Original\autoexp.cs"`
6. copy the generated file `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\Original\autoexp.dll` under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\Original`

Note> I wanted to force a 2 digit format but I did not manage to do that. So if anyone know how to do it I'm interested. I tried {Day:00} and {Day:D2} but both generate an exception.